# jQuery Mobile - How to read JSON and display form search results?

Tags: json, forms, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm currently trying to make the first steps into jQuery Mobile.
So I'm developing an app for train timetables. Nothing too complicated.

I enter some info regarding the departure, arrival, hours, etc.
The query url looks something like this:
[Example Query](http://poucaterra.joaodias.me/app/cp/getdata.php?departure=coimbra&arrival=aveiro&day=2012-08-25&hour=20)

Now, if you go to the app index in http://poucaterra.joaodias.me/app/index.html

*(and try, for example, to enter the same values in the app.
Enter "coimbra" for departure, "aveiro" for arrival, "2012-08-25" for the date and 20 for the hour)*

the display result is just a blank page saying "undefined".

So, what is the best way for me to pass the returned JSON values, read them and send them to another page with a listview, hence displaying the search results?

Please, if it is not asking too much, show me examples with my current code.
Because since I'm taking baby steps at this, I've already tried to read through code in other, but I just can't seem to figure out where to put what, when, how...*sighs* I am such a noob at this!
Thanks :)

Ah, almost forgot.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="pt"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="pt"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="pt"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="pt"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pouca Terra</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Pouca Terra - Train timetables">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />

        <!-- Apple Start Icon -->
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon.png"/>
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-ipad.png" />
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-iphone4.png" />
            <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="apple-touch-startup-image.png" />

        <!-- CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/themes/poucaTerra.css"/>



        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="assets/js/lib/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
<!--
****************************************************
***************** PAGE: 1 - SEARCH FORM PAGE *************  
****************************************************
-->
            <div data-role="page" id="search">
                <!-- HEADER TOP BAR -->
                    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                        <h4>Pouca Terra</h4>
                    </div>
                <!-- END HEADER TOP BAR -->

                <!-- CONTENT FORM -->
                    <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
                        <form id="search-form" action="cp/getdata.php?" method="get">
                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                        <label for="textinput1">
                                            Departure
                                        </label>
                                        <input name="departure" id="textinput1" placeholder="Estação de Origem" value="" type="text" />
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>

                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                        <label for="textinput2">
                                            Arrival
                                        </label>
                                        <input name="arrival" id="textinput2" placeholder="Estação de Destino" value="" type="text" />
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>

                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                    <label for="textinput3">
                                            Date
                                        </label>
                                        <input name="day" id="textinput3" placeholder="Formato: aaaa-mm-dd" value="" type="date" />
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>

                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                        <label for="slider1">
                                            Hour
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="range" name="hour" id="slider1" value="hour" min="0" max="24" data-highlight="true" data-track-theme="b" />
                                    </fieldset>
                                </div>

                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                <!-- END CONTENT FORM -->

            </div>
<!-- ***************** PAGE: 1 - END SEARCH FORM PAGE ************* -->


<!--
****************************************************
***************** PAGE: 2 - RESULTS TRAIN TIMETABLES *************  
****************************************************
-->
            <div data-role="page" id="results">

                <!-- HEADER TOP BAR -->
                    <div data-theme="d" data-role="header">
                        <h4>Resultados</h4>
                    </div>
                <!-- END HEADER TOP BAR -->

                <!-- CONTENT FORM -->
                    <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="d" data-counttheme="e">  

                        </ul>  
                    </div>
                <!-- END CONTENT FORM -->

            </div>
<!-- ***************** PAGE: 2- END RESULTS TRAIN TIMETABLES ************* -->

        <!-- *** Javascript at the bottom (for performance purposes) *** -->
            <!-- Add to Home -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    if ('standalone' in navigator && !navigator.standalone && (/iphone|ipod|ipad/gi).test(navigator.platform) && (/Safari/i).test(navigator.appVersion)) {
                        var addToHomeConfig = {
                            animationIn:'bubble',       // Animation In
                            animationOut:'drop',        // Animation Out
                            lifespan:30000,             // The popup lives 30 seconds
                            expire:2,                   // The popup is shown only once every 2 minutes
                            touchIcon:true,
                            message:''
                        };
                        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/add2home.css">');
                        document.write('<script type="application/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/add2home.js"><\/s' + 'cript>');
                    }
                </script>

            <!--jquery-->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery-1.8.min.js"></script>

            <!--jquery mobile-->                    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery-1.8.min.js"></script>
                <script src="assets/js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

            <!--bootstrap datepicker-->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

            <!-- Application Javascript -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/pages/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's great that you provided so much info (kudos), but I found it a little difficult to understand the core issue.  It seems something like "I have page A, which the user builds a query on, then they get redirected to page B which runs that query; how do I pass the query itself from page A to page B?", but I'm not sure if I have that right ... can you maybe try to clarify the core issue/question please?

Comment: Hey! Yep. That's it. :)

Lol you preety much resumed a bloat of text into 4 lines :)

But as I was reading your text, I wondered this: Do I perform the query in the first page (the one with the form) or the second one (the one with the listview with the results)?

Jeez, someone help me out here :)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I perform the query in the first page (the one with the form) or
>   the second one (the one with the listview with the results)?

Either one can work, but here's my advice: it depends on whether you're talking about "real" pages, or JS-generated ones.

In traditional, page-based web development, the basic pattern is this:

1. Build the query on page #1
2. Submit it, either with a GET string (eg. "`?foo=bar`") or with POST data (ie. submitting a form, where the fields on the form hold your query information)
3. Your server returns page #2, with the query results

You *could* have page #1 pass the query to page #2 (via a GET string, or a cookie, or passing the query to the server in-between), and then have page #2 make the query via AJAX ... but since you have to get page #2 anyway, it just makes sense to submit the query with that request.

However, with mobile development a "page" often doesn't involve navigating to a new URL at all; instead, you just use DOM manipulation to change the "page" (eg. "`$('#oldPage').remove(); $(body).append(newPage)`;").  In this case, you generally make the query via an AJAX call, and since there's no real page transition "passing the query" is as simple as passing a JS variable from one function to the next.

In this style, it often makes sense to have your code for "page #2" make the actual AJAX request.

Hopefully that helps, but I feel like I might not have answered your question fully, so comment back if you have any questions.